# Warning about unavailable repositories

Tags: update-manager

An icon has recently appeared on my panel with an exclamation mark. The message i get when hovering over this is that the update information is out of date, and that this may be caused by an unavailable repository or a network isssue.

My network connection appears to be ok.

The message advises i manually check for updates. When i do this, i get the following message:

> W:Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net///ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/source/Sources.gz
>   404  Not Found , W:Failed to fetch
>   http://ppa.launchpad.net///ubuntu/dists/maverick/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
>   404  Not Found , E:Some index files
>   failed to download, they have been
>   ignored, or old ones used instead.

Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Answer (score 2):

The best way I have found of solving most problems with "failed to fetch" is to check that you are using the best server. The reason this works is that in the process of selecting the best server it has to ping each of the available servers to find the one that responds the fastest. If there is anything wrong at your end the entire process would probably fail otherwise it my select a different server if the one you normally use is down for maintenance. I personally do this as one of those "after Installation todo's"

---

- The function can be found in software
  sources which can be accessed through
  the software centre's edit menu

[image: Software Centre Edit menu]

- Then select other from the server
  menu

[image: Server selection menu]

- And finally hit the Choose the best
  server button

[image: Choose server dialogue]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

That said - it would appear that those urls do not exist.

Check that you have up to date information for the ppas you are using.

If any are not correct that will likely be your problem - you can remove the source list for the respective ppas either from software sources - which I think is accessible from the settings options in update manager/software centre or synaptic.

Alternatively they will be listed in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ and can be removed with rm

eg

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nameoflist.list

Once they have been removed

sudo apt-get update