# I can't remove a package - what should I do?

Tags: package-management, uninstall

I'm trying to remove libavcodec52 package but it won't work. If I try through Software Central it just tells me it didn't work and to check my internet conection.

If I try it at the terminal, this is what I get

```
Souljacker Ahab @: ~ $ sudo apt-get remove libavcodec52
Reading package lists ... ready
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... ready
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer needed:
   libmodplug1 libtwolame0 libva-1-x11-libxcb libxcb-keysyms1 xv0 libcddb2 libass4 libdvbpsi6 libvlc5 libupnp3 libxcb-7-randr0 libiso9660 libkate1 vlc-data
   libtar libvlccore4 libvcdinfo0 libebml3 libmpcdec6 libmatroska3 libsdl-image1.2 liba52-0.7.4
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
   libavcodec libavformat-extra-extra-52-52 libopenjpeg2 librtmp0
Suggested packages:
   libfaad0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
   libavcodec52 libavformat52 vlc vlc vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify-plugin-pulse
The following NEW packages will be installed:
   libavcodec libavformat-extra-extra-52-52 libopenjpeg2 librtmp0
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 6 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
You must download kB/5.489 127 kB file.
After this operation, 12.1MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y / n]? s
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ Natty / universe libopenjpeg2 i386 1.3 + dfsg-4
   404 Not Found
Err http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ Natty / universe librtmp0 i386 2.3-2
   404 Not Found
Http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjpeg/libopenjpeg2_1.3+dfsg-4_i386.deb Failed to fetch 404 Not Found
Http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtmpdump/librtmp0_2.3-2_i386.deb Failed to fetch 404 Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with - fix-missing?
```

I've tried an apt-get update and nothing changes.

Any help?

Comment: `LANG=C apt-get ...` will print the message in the default language (English, technically C is for POSIX). This makes it easier to discuss the problem in an international forum.

Comment: Your terminal output is not in English, which might make it difficult for lots of people to answer your question. You should consider temporarily changing languages and reposting the output. Or at least translating the error messages.

Comment: @Souljacker Welcome! i have added the google translation if you think that is the correct translation you may remove the Portuguese ;)

Comment: I was just thinking about the language issue, so I swiched Ubuntu to English and also changed it's default repository to the original instead of the one in Brazil. And that was it. Now removal is working ;)  I've seem plenty of Brazilian people with the very same problem while searching for a solution. Maybe this will help then :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29600/warning-about-unavailable-repositories/29648#29648  Try updating your server and then try the command again

Comment: @Souljacker Answer your own question with the solution

Answer (score 1):

Edit: `apt` is also part of the problem, but DoR is right, the main problem is with connection to Brazilian mirror, so change of mirror will solve this problem as well.

---

There are some packages depending on libavcodec52 (in my system I've found mplayer, but also vlc and maybe other multimedia applications) and it seems apt can't resolve this conflict.

You can try to remove those applications first (I see VLC in the apt output) and then remove libavcodecs52 or install `aptitude` which has better system for resolving conflicts.

`aptitude` has similar syntax, so you can remove packages using

`sudo aptitude remove package`

Tried and worked for me - apt is "stuck" but aptitude offers removing of mplayer and that solves the problem (libavcodecs52 is removed properly without installing anything new).

Answer (score 1):

I did a little searching and it seems [the problem](http://araujomatheus.wordpress.com/2011/05/23/erro-ao-instalar-ubuntu-restricted-extras/) is with the Brazilian repository
mirror <sup>(`http://br.archive.ubuntu.com`)</sup>.
Go to *Software Center ➜ Edit ➜ Software Sources...* and change the download server.

Comment: AS i'VE SAID UP THERE, THERE WAS IT. tHANKS A LOT :)